# Image as Sales Badge

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I am replacing the sales badge on the woocommerce products page with an image. I have succesfully done this by adding the following to my functions.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'vs_change_sale_content', 10, 3);
function vs_change_sale_content($content, $post, $product){
   $content = '<span class="onsale"><img src="http://localhost:8888/marmalade/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/in-stock.png"></span>';
   return $content;
}
```

This, however, uses a hardcoded url for the image. How can I replace the source with my theme folder? So that when I change servers The url is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

Change your image url to "/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/in-stock.png"

That way even if you change servers (or changed domain name), as long as the filepath doesn't change from wp-content, you'll still be safe.